# Flutter 3 : Warning : Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null

Tags: flutter, widget, warnings, flutter-upgrade

I just upgraded to Flutter 3 and my flutter project console is full of warnings.
Did anyone know how to fix these warnings or should I wait for the stable update from flutter itself.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the presence of outdated packages. You can fix this by running `flutter pub upgrade` inside your app directory

Comment: There is no guarantee that all new package versions are available.

Comment: That's true. But several packages are already updated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it suggests you to remove the '!' operand because the class method you have used now returns an Object of type "WidgetBinding" instead of "WidgetBinding?".